# ubuntu not installing along with windows

Tags: shutdown, laptop

I tried to install Ubuntu along with Windows. When I try to install it, It will ask for Try Ubuntu and it is getting shutdown. I installed the same version previously in my laptop and it worked fine at that time. I tried changing the USB drive and versions but its the same. But windows is working fine.

Comment: Please view the following articles and list the error message shown on the screen so we have a direction to provide solutions. [Youtube, Adam Macdonald: **How to Dual-Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 (& 17.10!)**](https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-guide-2200653) [LifeWire: The Ultimate Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux Dual Boot Guide ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNeJvujdB-0) [Tecmint: How to Install Ubuntu 16.10/16.04 Alongside With Windows 10 or 8 in Dual-Boot](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/)

Comment: The problem is like when Ubuntu loading is going on it will get shutdown. Its like a hard reset for the laptop